# What happens while starting cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra.. But i have some basic doubt on starting cassandra node.

```
When I have many keyspaces,does Cassandra load all the keyspaces into cache on startup?
or loads specific property of Keyspces to the cache?.
```

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have cache saving enabled, Cassandra will load the most recent snapshot of the key and/or row caches.  Otherwise, no specific preheating will be done.  (Typically, Cassandra datasets are much larger than system memory.)

Comment: @jbellis.I have more than 100 keyspaces and each carries more than 100000 records.I have enabled row chache and key cache..I did not do any read on any of keyspaces.Just done write operation only.After restarting cassandra I inspected heap usage via JMX. It has obviously increased.what may be the reason.What it is having in cache?.